# Find closest Node in a binary tree Function returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, binary-tree

I am trying to solve a question in which you have to find the node in a binary tree whose value is closest to the value given by the user, My function returns undefined, can someone help.
Here's the function i wrote..
The variable currClosestNode is defined globally

```js
   closestNode(value, node,diff) {
    
    if(node === null) {
        return currClosestNode;
    }
    if(node.value === value) {
        return node;
    }
    const newDiff = Math.abs(value - node.value);
    if (newDiff < diff) {
        diff = newDiff;
        currClosestNode = node;
        if(node.value >= value) {
            return this.closestNode(value, node.leftNode, diff);
        }  
        else if(node.value < value){
            return this.closestNode(value, node.rightNode, diff);
        }
    }
    else if(newDiff >= diff) {
        if(node.value < value) {
            return this.closestNode(value,node.rightNode,diff);
        }
        else {
            return this.closestNode(value, node.leftNode,diff);
        }
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside the if statements, you just call the function. You should replace them as return statements. E.g. if(node.value >= value) {
                return this.closestNode(value, node.leftNode, diff);
            }

Comment: Basically, the undefined is because your function does not return anything in few cases.

Comment: @edison16029 thank you for responding, I tried returning in those cases, But still the function returns undefined. In those few cases you mentioned, where i am not returning anything.. there i am making a recursive call to the function...

Comment: The recursive calls makes sense but, the recursive calls should return something which must be returned by the current function call in the stack. Can you update the code you tried with return statements?

Comment: @edison16029 i have updated the code... please check